# Master thesis with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am student of CS and I'd like to write my master thesis mostly in ReactJS (because I would like to learn it). One of requirement of master thesis is, that it have to have "research part" of it. So now I am wondering what topic connected with this technology could be to meet this requirement. I had an idea to create app to support runners (saving their workouts and parameters from pulsometers etc.) But it seems to not have this research part of topic. Unfortunately I cannot came up with other idea for a topic for my Master Thesis to arrange React with it. Maybe you guys, have some ideas? it would be really helpful.

Comment: This is a question that would be better suited to a discussion, not an answer—it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Try [r/javascript](https://reddit.com/r/javascript), [discuss.reactjs.org](https://discuss.reactjs.org/) or even the [JS room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) on Stack Overflow chat.

Comment: Thanks for advice!

Comment: not sure exactly what qualifies as research for you, but the react virtual DOM and the DOM diff algo is pretty cool, is that the sort of thing youre looking for? perhaps some guidance for us non PhDs...

Comment: Not directly related to React itself, but one suggestion would be to compare/contrast accepted best practice design patterns.  One of the most exciting aspects of React is that it turns the concept of MVC on it's head and readdresses the concepts of coupling and cohesion in a new way.  A research paper on how different tools are addressing those concerns sounds both research heavy and like it would be really valuable.